# Navigation Bar missing after segue from VC in UITabBarController

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, segue

I am using a custom framework which subclasses `UITabBarController` and is embedded in a `NavigationController`. I have three `UIViewControllers` within the `UITabBarController`.

In one of my `UIViewController`s, I want to navigate to another `UIViewController` that's not managed by the `UITabBarController`. I used a segue for this, which did work, but upon the new VC loading, there is no  navigation bar and no back button so I can go back to the VC managed by the `UITabBarController`.

How can I accomplish this? In short, I just want to be able to navigate from a VC managed by my `UITabBarController`, to a VC not managed by it, and back.

[image]

The bottom right most VC is the one not managed by the `UITabBarController` that I am trying to navigate to from the VC directly to its left

Comment: The title of your topic doesn't make sense.

Comment: @ElTomato I tried to make it more clear

Comment: Let me assume that your final destination is the view controller shown at the bottom-right corner appearing in your image.  Does it have a navigation controller embedded?

Comment: @ElTomato Yes you're right, I want to navigate to the VC in the bottom right corner from the VC to its left. It does not have a navigation controller embedded, would this be my problem? I'm not too versed in navigation controllers unfortunately. I want to be able to "go back" from the bottom right VC after navigating to it, but currently there is no navigation bar after performing my segue

Comment: "would this be my problem?"  If it doesn't have a navigation bar, it won't show a navigation bar.  Select your destination view controller and choose Editor > Embeded in > Navigation Controller.

Comment: Did exactly that and still no navigation bar. My destination controller is embedded in a navigation controller. Also, I thought it was a fair assumption it would have a bar since it has a push segue from a VC that does have a bar

Comment: It also shows a back button in the interface builder

Answer (score 0):

Each tab (view controller) of your tab bar controller should have own navigation controller.

Then you can show next view controller using show segue from your tab.

Comment: Hm this still doesn't seem to be working for me. I embedded my VC in my tab with a navigation controller, but when I try to print my navigation controller at the time I try to segue, it is nil?